# Iterating through folders in R

Tags: r

I am trying to iterate through a list of folders then set my working directory to that folder so I can run a function on that code. I came up with this, but it isnt working quite like I expected

```
dirs<-list.dirs("C:\\Users\\King\\Desktop\\stuff")

temp<-function(fileName)
{
print(fileName)
flush.console()
}

foreach(n=1:length(dirs)) %do% temp(dirs[n])
```

I wind up with a whole bunch of nulls at then end. Am I printing all elements of a one element list or something?

Comment: The return value from each iteration of the for loop is what gets returned from `flush.console`, which is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do a for loop, use lapply.

```
lapply(dirs, temp)
```